# Get Access Token Without Sign In

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docusignapi

I am trying to build an application that will be authenticating documents using DocuSign.

The person who is signing the document is going to be initiating the process and will not have any login credentials for DocuSign.

However, when I test using the JWT authentication method it always brings me to a page asking for a Username/Password. My end user is not going to have this information.

All of the Example applications do not address Authentication, they just have you copy and past the Access_Token out of their tool on the website.

How can I have an Embedded Signing application that does not require the End User to login with DocuSign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT Authentication requires the user grant consent *once*. Once that consent is granted, the application can freely generate access tokens for that user at any time (unless consent is later revoked).

For an example of C# / .net core that uses JWT authentication, please see GitHub: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-core

Comment: When you say they must grant consent once, do you mean once on each machine? Or they grant access once and it will work on all machines?

Comment: Once per user & integration key. Not machine-specific.

Comment: Sorry I am new to DocuSign, but what do you mean by User. In the docs it looks like User is just a string ID that is up to the implementer to come up with. Can I potentially use 1 user for all of my signers? I will potentially have thousands of signers, do I have to create a user per signer?

Comment: I think I am just getting confused by the documentation, https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken 

step 1 only needs to be done once, and is not part of the process for obtaining the access token everytime?

Comment: Correct. For JWT authentication, the 'Request Application Consent' step only needs to be performed once for the authenticating user.

Comment: Thanks, so the code that is returned from the Step 1 is not used for anything? I was thinking that this was part of the authorize process which was throwing me off.

Comment: The code from step 1 is used in the Auth Code Grant workflow, but not used in the JWT workflow.

Answer (score 0):

JWT allows you to specify a userId. 
If you are an admin of the DocuSign account and you enabled the integration and logged in yourself at least once, then you can later make APIs call impersonating other users, if you provide their userId in the request so they don't need to login themselves.

Hope this helps